# Docker push on local registry gets stuck

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-api

I'm trying to push an image to a local docker registry deployed with docker-compose the following way:

```yaml
services:
  docker-registry:
    image: registry:2
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true
    volumes:
      - registry-data:/var/lib/registry
```

Note: this is inside a Dev Container and registry port is forwarded directly from `.devcontainer.json`, but it is equivalent to forwarding `5000:5000` in docker-compose, I have no problem contacting the registry

Whenever I attempt to push an image on the registry, I have a layer getting stuck to 48.8MB (attempted a lot of times, recreating the service, deleting the volume, restarting everything)

```bash
 ~ docker push localhost:5000/some-image
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/some-image]
1562583dd903: Preparing 
1562583dd903: Pushing  227.3kB/19.88MB
1562583dd903: Pushing   6.14MB/19.88MB
1562583dd903: Pushing  9.122MB/19.88MB
1562583dd903: Pushing   18.3MB/19.88MB
1562583dd903: Pushing  19.98MB
86959104e6a0: Pushed 
86959104e6a0: Pushing  18.25MB/2.068GB
86959104e6a0: Pushing   22.7MB/2.068GB
86959104e6a0: Pushing  50.83MB/2.068GB
a3038b-3bfe-4903-951d-8d5529552f96 
c735c85250bd: Mounted from some-other-image
b0f6b3bc04d7: Mounted from some-other-image 
f31afd463445: Mounted from some-other-image 
a9099c3159f5: Pushing [===================>                               ]   48.8MB/124.1MB
```

The command is then stuck forever. I tried pushing from docker command on my host and also from docker API using Golang code, I have encountered the same exact behaviour.

Any idea on what is wrong here?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. When I try, it works as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem (but not the reason), this seems related to Dev Containers.

I ran the service this way in the `docker-compose.yml` run by `devcontainer.json`:

```yaml
services:
  docker-registry:
    image: registry:2
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true
    volumes:
      - registry-data:/var/lib/registry
```

In `devcontainer.json`, I forwarded the ports this way as I'm used to doing to have the ports listed in VS Code ports section:

```json
"forwardPorts": [
  "docker-registry:5000",
],
"portsAttributes": {
  "docker-registry:5000": {
    "label": "Docker registry",
    "onAutoForward": "silent",
    "requireLocalPort": true
}
```

This resulted in correct forward of port 5000 of the container to port 5000 on the localhost.

However, by removing these references from `.devcontainer` and forwarding ports directly from the `docker-compose.yml`, I no longer have the initial issue:

```yaml
services:
  docker-registry:
    image: registry:2
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true
    volumes:
      - registry-data:/var/lib/registry
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```